# Need help printing the powers of two

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

The method printPowersOf2 accepts a max number as the argument and prints each power of 2 from 2^0 up to that max number.

printPowersOf2(3); outputs 1 2 4 8
printPowersOf2(5); outputs 1 2 4 8 16 32

I can't seem to figure out the right code to print. I have to use a loop and the *= operator. Math class not allowed. I know its something so simple too

Here is my code

```
public class Chap3LabP2 {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    printPowersof2(3);
    printPowersof2(5);
    printPowersof2(10);
    printPowersof2(12);


  }

  public static void printPowersof2(int maxNum){
    System.out.print("1" + " ");
    for(int i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++){
      System.out.print(i*2 + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("");
  }


}
```

Comment: So use the `*=` operator, what have you tried? Have you tried using a second variable for example?

Comment: @assylias: 2^i != pow(2,i) too

Comment: My answer should help you out. Check it out!

Comment: @Adam: Yeah yeah, i´ve seen your Xor before you edited it. Be glad for the upvote and don´t beg for me to reverse it again.

Comment: @deviantfan it was a maths `^` as in the introduction of the question. But I get your point.

Comment: Ok...but at least, in Adam´s case it´s clearly java code

Comment: I don't believe I ever used an xor...

Answer (score 3):

Before the loop set i = 2. The loop body should be (pseudocode):

i *= 2

Print i

Answer (score 1):

You can store the value of current power and in each iteration of the cycle multiply it by 2.

```
int pow = 1;
for(int i = 1; i <= maxNum; i++){
    pow = pow * 2;
    System.out.print(pow + " ");
}
```

Comment: I see! so you created a new variable, initialized that at 1, then multiplied that by two each time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void printPowersof2(int maxNum) {
    int power = 0;
    int answer = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (power <= maxNum) {
            System.out.println(answer);
        } else { 
            return;
        }
        answer *= 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I see how this would work. Unfortunately I cant use anything we haven't covered in class yet, so I have to avoid while loops.